# Error 400.0 when returning DTO in Controller and Azure Mobile Client Sync Table

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Since the object we need in the Mobile Client needs to access its related/associated objects, we decided to return an objectDTO instead of the object when the GetAllObjects method in the controller is called.

Using Postman to query the Backend Server results to the proper behaviour, the retrieved list has all the properties of the DTO.

Problem arises when using the Mobile Client. According to the logs, an "HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request" happened and "The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax." is indicated under "More Information."

**I dont know why this error happened**. I updated the Object class in the Client App to match the ObjectDTO class in the server. For comparison:

**ObjectDTO in Server**

```
public class SaleDto
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public string PromoterId { get; set; }
        public string StoreId { get; set; }
        public string PaymentMethodId { get; set; }
        public bool CorporateSale { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateSold { get; set; }
        public double PriceSold { get; set; }
        public int QuantitySold { get; set; }
        public string Remarks { get; set; }
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        public byte[] Version { get; set; }

        public string ProductSku { get; set; }
        public string ProductPartNumber { get; set; }
        public string StoreName { get; set; }
        public string PaymentMethodName { get; set; }
    }
```

**Object Model in Client App**

```
public class Sale
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "productId")]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "promoterId")]
    public string PromoterId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "storeId")]
    public string StoreId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "paymentMethodId")]
    public string PaymentMethodId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "corporateSale")]
    public bool CorporateSale { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "dateSold")]
    public DateTime? DateSold { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "priceSold")]
    public double PriceSold { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "quantitySold")]
    public int QuantitySold { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "remarks")]
    public string Remarks { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "deleted")]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "createdAt")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "updatedAt")]
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "productSku")]
    public string ProductSku { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "productPartNumber")]
    public string ProductPartNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "storeName")]
    public string StoreName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "paymentMethodName")]
    public string PaymentMethodName { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set;}
    public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
    public virtual PaymentMethod PaymentMethod { get; set; }
}
```

**Or it might be because of the Sync Tables?** Here's the code that handles syncing (stuff has been omitted for brevity)

```
public class DataStore
{
    private static DataStore _instance;

    public MobileServiceClient MobileService { get; set; }

    IMobileServiceSyncTable<Sale> saleTable;

    public static DataStore Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new DataStore();
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private DataStore()
    {
        MobileService = new MobileServiceClient("url");

        var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("tabletable.db");

        store.DefineTable<Sale>();

        MobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);

        saleTable = MobileService.GetSyncTable<Sale>();
    }

    public async Task<Sale> AddSaleAsync(Sale sale)
    {
        await saleTable.InsertAsync(sale);
        bool wasPushed = await SyncSalesAsync();
        if (wasPushed) return null;
        return sale;
    }

    public async Task<List<Sale>> GetSalesAsync(int take = 20, int skip = 0)
    {
        IEnumerable<Sale> items = await saleTable
            .Where(sale => !sale.Deleted)
            .OrderByDescending(sale => sale.CreatedAt)
            .Take(take)
            .Skip(skip)
            .ToEnumerableAsync();

        return new List<Sale>(items);
    }

    public async Task<bool> SyncSalesAsync()
    {
        ReadOnlyCollection<MobileServiceTableOperationError> syncErrors = null;
        bool wasPushed = true;

        try
        {
            await MobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();
            await saleTable.PullAsync("allSales", saleTable.CreateQuery());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"/Sale/ Catch all. Sync error: {0}", e.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }

        return wasPushed;
    }
}
```

**Any kind of help will be much appreciated.**

Comment: Are you using the right version of the mobile client SDK?  You will get a BadRequest if the versions do not match up. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-client-and-server-versioning/

Comment: @lindydonna-msft the versions do not match. Mobile.Client is 2.0.1 while Mobile.Server is 1.0.119 However, extending/adding EntityData to the DTO solved the problem. but a malformed syntax problem arose with posting to the server. i guess i'll make a new post for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having SaleDto extend/implement EntityData solved the problem

`public class SaleDto : EntityData`